"Die" is a verb, "death" is a noun. "Perish" is a verb, but what's the noun for this verb?
"Die" is to "death" like "perish" to what?
I'm interested in whether there's any noun for the verb "perish".

Nothing I'm aware of, but it could be an interesting question for ELU to find out if there ever was one.

The word is perishment, although it's really rather uncommon - not all dictionaries list it.

From that dictionary: 1) "perishment - the act of perishing" - i.e. like "dying" rather than "death"; 2) "perishment - something that perishes (another thing)" - I couldn't understand this explanation - is it like "death"?

No, that example defines a use of perishment that corresponds to the (unusual) use of perish as a transitive verb. So an example would be something like "his perishment was hunger/a sword". I'm pretty sure that I have never encountered the word perishment in my life, and I'm certain that I have never encountered it in this sense, or indeed perish as a transitive verb. With one exception: the idiom "perish the thought", which means "don't even think that" (usually in a sense of generosity - don't even think of thanking or repaying). I'd never realised that it used transitive "perish".

Your question assumes that for every verb there is a related noun.
This is not true.  There is no regular grammatical process that forms nouns from verbs.
So the question is not answerable.

It's inspired from old french perissement.
In English, the noun for perish is perishment.

Usage Area:
This word is used in northern English regional dialect and northern Scottish English.
How common is the noun perishment?
Fewer than 0.01 occurrences per million words in modern written English.

Source: Oxford English Dictionary
